# .htaccess <Files> locking me out of subdirectories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following in a `.htaccess` file on my server:

```
<Files index.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from 80.168.22.149
</Files>
```

The `.htaccess` is located in a subdirectory, at [www.example.com/subdir/.htaccess](http://www.example.com/subdir/.htaccess)

The `index.php` file is located **in the same** subdirectory.

It gives the usual error if I try and access the page from another IP:

```
Forbidden

You do not have permission to access this document.
```

However, when I try and access a subdirectory such as `/subdir/images`, I get the same error. **This error appears if I try and access from an allowed OR disallowed IP address.** I thought that the `<Files>` limitation would only disallow access to the specified files?

I need to be the only IP address that can access `index.php`, but I need to be able to link to subdirectories within `/subdir/` and let anyone view them.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `<Files>` directive you can use this rewrite rule in `/subdir/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdir/

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !=80.168.22.149
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not fix the problem. Subdirectories of `/subdir/` are still inaccessible.

Comment: Are you sure Apache is getting `80.168.22.149` IP address? This rule cannot block anything but `/subdir/.htaccess`. Are there more rules? Try in a different browser.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your `<Files>` directive is that it is matching every `index.php` including the `index.php` files in the sub directories.

The only way around this is to use a `<Location>` directive instead, but you're not able to use that in a `.htaccess` file.

You would need to edit the Apache configuration file instead and add the `<Location>` directive in there inside the `<VirtualHost>` directive for the domain

Comment: the `/subdir/images/` directory I'm trying to access doesn't have an `index.php` file in it, so why would this one be disallowed? Could, theoretically, each subdirectory have it's own `.htaccess` re-allowing access?

Comment: What file/files does `/subdir/images/` have in it? If you change the directive to index2.php are you then able to access the subdir?

Comment: `/images/` has a couple of PNG files within so far, and nothing more. With the directive at `index2.php`, I still do not have access unfortunately.

Comment: So what happens when you remove the directive altogether? Without an index file in there most servers would always give you a 403 Forbidden message